# No '/boot' and '/boot/efi' partition after successfully boot

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, partitioning, grub

There was two nvme SSDs on my PC: Win10 on nvme0 and Ubuntu20 on nvme1.  After removing nvme0, my PC boot failed with `grub` command waiting.  I realized that it boot from the EFI of the nvme0, now the PC can't find nvme0.  So I searched for something like 'how to boot from grub', and it worked.  However, it keeps waiting at booting process until time out about 90 seconds, for this:

```
[ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/831A-5511.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /boot/efi.
[DEPEND] ...
...
```

I believe that `831A-5511` is the UUID of EFI partition on the absent nvme0, and it does exist on the `/etc/fstab` as the auto-mount EFI partition.

Moreover, when I run `df`, there is nothing about `/boot` and '/boot/efi'.

I want to alter the EFI auto-mount entry in `/etc/fstab` to the EFI partition on my nvme1, so I need to get the UUID of it first. BUT, `fdisk -l` displays that there is no UUID of the nvme0 EFI partition.  So I cannot fix it.

Or I just do nothing, since my PC can boot but wait for 1m30s every time.

Comment: But, `fdisk -l` never shows any UUIDs in the first place. What does `lsblk -f` (or maybe `lsblk -o name,partlabel,size,fstype,label,mountpoint`) show?

Comment: Wow, thx! @user1686 It was solved by using `lsblk`.